# Java 8 Functions - compose and andThen

Tags: java, function, functional-programming

I find my Java knowledge out-of-date with Java 8, and there are many new language features I am trying to learn. One of them is Functions, specifically the `compose` and `andThen` methods.

I have written a trivial experiment to test the reversibility of `compose` and `andThen`:

```
/** Wraps a value 
 */
public class Wrap<T> {
    private final T value;
    private Wrap(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static <T> Wrap<T> of(T value) {
        return new Wrap<>(value);
    }
}

static void functions() {

    Function<Integer,String> itos = i->"'"+i+"'";
    Function<String,Wrap<String>> stow = s->Wrap.of(s);

    Function<Integer,Wrap<String>> itow = itos.andThen(stow);
    Function<Integer,Wrap<String>> itow2 = stow.compose(itos);

    System.out.println(itow.apply(3));
    System.out.println(itow2.apply(3));
}
```

In the above code, as expected, the 2 Functions `itow` and `itow2` seem to be equivalent. But are they actually equivalent? Do the have the same result somewhat by accident in this case?

The thought occurs that both `compose` and `andThen` methods exist for a reason, and that Functions or BiFunctions might not always be reversible in this way. Can you think of any cases where the reversibility would not apply?

Comment: On further thought, I was running into confusion with BiFunction, and of course they don't have compose() for obvious reasons. Looks like Functions don't actually need compose() at all, andThen() is much more intuitive IMO.

Answer (score 38):

While `a.andThen(b)` is equivalent to `b.compose(a)`, there’s a practical difference at the use side, when only one of these two functions is an already existing function.

Suppose, you have the already existing function

```
Function<Integer, String> iToHex = i -> "'" + Integer.toHexString(i) + "'";
```

and then, you want to chain a string transformation, e.g.

```
Function<Integer, String> itoUpperHex = iToHex.andThen(String::toUpperCase);
```

`andThen` obviously is much more convenient, compared to

```
Function<Integer,String> itoUpperHex
                       = ((Function<String,String>)String::toUpperCase).compose(iToHex);
```

On the other hand, if your already existing function is

```
Function<String, String> quote = s -> "'" + s + "'";
```

and you want to create the quoted hex function,

```
Function<Integer, String> iToHex = quote.compose(Integer::toHexString);
```

will be much more convenient, compared to

```
Function<Integer, String> iToHex = ((Function<Integer, String>) Integer::toHexString).andThen(quote);
```

---

So the decision for either method depends on which function already exists. If both are already existing functions, it doesn’t matter which method you use (unless you suspect that one of these functions might have overridden these methods to perform a more efficient composition). If you have no existing function as starting point, there is no reason to use any of these methods, as you can write the composed expression as a single lambda expression.

Answer (score 7):

They are equivalent.

Or in other words: `x.andThen(y)` is the same as `y.compose(x)`.

Comment: Yes but why the introduced 2 methods?

Comment: They give same output, but the sequence in which they work is different, see my answer

Comment: @mtj No they are not same order of evaluation is different in both the cases

`compose` is evaluated from righ --> left while `andThen()` is evaluated from left --> right

Answer (score 7):

From the Javadocs, there's a clear difference between `compose` and `andThen`:

- [compose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-)...

> Returns a composed function that first applies the before function to its input, and then applies this function to the result.

- [andThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-)...

> Returns a composed function that first applies this function to its input, and then applies the after function to the result.

As such, reversibility will depend on the implementation of your function.

In your case, `itow` and `itow2` are just two alternative ways of expressing the same: "run `itos`, then `stow` in this order".

Comment: How will reversibility depend on the implementation of my function? Surely whether the 2 functions can be chained in this way depends only on the result type of one and input type of the next?

Comment: @NickJ I only meant that generally, i.e. some transformations might not be reversible, even regardless of the input/output types. This is not your case here of course.

Comment: then why thy create two methods? why not just replacing as x.andThen(y) to y.andThen(x) ?

Answer (score 5):

The source code for `Function` is freely available:

```
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(before);
    return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
}

default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
}
```

From this it's pretty clear that `a.andThen(b)` is equivalent to `b.compose(a)`.

It's perhaps even clearer if we make the implied `this` explicit:

```
return (V v) -> this .apply(before.apply(v)); //compose
return (T t) -> after.apply(this  .apply(t)); // andThen
```

---

You may ask, if they're equivalent, why do both exist?

Well, they're only there as a convenience in the first place. You could manage without either of them:

```
 a.andThen(b)
```

... is of course equivalent to:

```
 (x) -> b.apply(a.apply(x));
```

So, given that they're there as a convenience, each is convenient in different circumstances. You can choose which is most expressive in a particular situation.

---

In many functional languages that don't use the `method` construct, the equivalent to `compose` and `andThen` are `compose` and `pipe`, which differ only in the order the composed functions are applied.

In those languages, these are all equivalent:

```
fn = x => a(b(c(x)))
fn = compose(a, b, c)
fn = pipe(c, b, a)
```

You can see that with `compose` the functions are written in the same order as they would be if you wrote them nested.

With `pipe` the functions are written in the order they'll be applied.

Which of those is appropriate depends on circumstances, how the coder's brain is working when they write it, and how the coder would like the reader's brain to work when they read it.

One style guide for Ramda suggests that one-liners should use `pipe` whereas multi-line compositions should use `compose`:

```
// one-liner
const toDocument = pipe(fillTemplate, addTitles, toPdf)
// multi-line
const toDocument = compose(
   toPdf,
   addTitles,
   fillTemplate
)
```

Java's `.compose()` and `.andThen()` are just the Java equivalent of this. Use the one that makes the code seem easiest to you. In terms of performance there is no significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

They are different in respect to the sequence in which they work.

A Simple example -

Program 1:

```
Function<String, String> x = myString -> myString + ",\tx function";
Function<String, String> y = myString -> myString + ",\ty function";

x = x.andThen(y);

System.out.println(x.apply("Hello"));
```

Output -

```
Hello,  x function, y function
```

Here, `x function` function gets executed **and then** `y function` gets executed

Program 2:

```
Function<String, String> x = myString -> myString + ",\tx function";
Function<String, String> y = myString -> myString + ",\ty function";

y = y.compose(x);

System.out.println(y.apply("Hello"));
```

Output -

```
Hello,  x function, y function
```

Here, `y function` **composes** `x function` first and then executes itself.

Thus, although outcome is same, the sequence of execution is different.

A second example -

```
        final double startNumber = 3.5;

        final Function<Double, Double> cubeRoot = x -> {
            System.out.println("Calculating cube root");
            return Math.pow(x, 1.0/3);
        };

        final Function<Double, Double> square = x -> {
            System.out.println("Calculating square");
            return Math.pow(x, 2);
        };

        final Function<Double, Long> round = x -> {
            System.out.println("Rounding");
            return Math.round(x);
        };

        Long result = cubeRoot.andThen(square).andThen(round).apply(startNumber);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);

        result = round.compose(square).compose(cubeRoot).apply(startNumber);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Output -

```
Calculating cube root
Calculating square
Rounding
Result: 2
Calculating cube root
Calculating square
Rounding
Result: 2
```

In `cubeRoot.andThen(square).andThen(round).apply(startNumber)` first `cubeRoot` is done, then `square` is done, then `round` is done.

In `round.compose(square).compose(cubeRoot).apply(startNumber)` first `cubeRoot` is composed and performed, then `square` is composed and performed, then `round` is composed and performed.

Thus, although outcome is same here too, the sequence of execution is different.

## **UPDATE**

Look at the following code -

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        int x = 1;

        String string1 = "Neha Wakes up";
        String string2 = "Brushes teeth";
        String string3 = "Goes to toilet";
        String string4 = "Takes a shower";
        String string5 = "Feeds the cat";
        String string6 = "Cleans the litter box";
        String string7 = "Eats breakfast";
        String string8 = "Goes for work";

        Function<Integer, Integer> step1 = a -> {
                stringBuilder.append(string1).append("\n");
                return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step2 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string2).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step3 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string3).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step4 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string4).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step5 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string5).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step6 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string6).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step7 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string7).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };
        Function<Integer, Integer> step8 = a -> {
            stringBuilder.append(string8).append("\n");
            return a+1;
        };

        int num1 = step1.andThen(step2).andThen(step3).andThen(step4).andThen(step5).andThen(step6).andThen(step7).andThen(step8).apply(x);
        System.out.println(num1);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

        stringBuilder.setLength(0);

        int num2 = step1.compose(step2).compose(step3).compose(step4).compose(step5).compose(step6).compose(step7).compose(step8).apply(x);
        System.out.println(num2);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

    }
}
```

Output -

```
9
Neha Wakes up
Brushes teeth
Goes to toilet
Takes a shower
Feeds the cat
Cleans the litter box
Eats breakfast
Goes for work

9
Goes for work
Eats breakfast
Cleans the litter box
Feeds the cat
Takes a shower
Goes to toilet
Brushes teeth
Neha Wakes up
```

This further proves my point. Here in both cases the numerical output is same that is 9. But in first case `andThen()` executes the chain from front to end, while `compose()` composes the chain first from end to front and then executes it.

Answer (score 3):

Both are similar except the sequence how it executes the functions, refer example below-

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionThenComposeTest {

    public static void main(String[] xavis_args) {

        Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = i -> {
            System.out.println("Inside F1");
            return i * i;
        };

        Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = i -> {
            System.out.println("Inside F2");
            return i * i;
        };

        System.out.println("And Then method");
        System.out.println(f1.andThen(f2).apply(2));// Execute f1 function first, take the result of f1 and then apply it to f2 function(The result of f1 function will be the input to f2 function)
        System.out.println("Compose method");        
        System.out.println(f1.compose(f2).apply(2));// First execute f2 function and then take the result of f2 and execute f1 (The result of f2 will be the input to f1 function)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
And Then method

Inside F1

Inside F2

16

Compose method

Inside F2

Inside F1

16
```

Comment: best answer provided

Answer (score 2):

I'd say they are equivalent, see the implementation:

`x.compose(y)` = `x.apply(y.apply(...))`

and

`y.andThen(x)` = `x.apply(y.apply(...))`

From `Function.java` (I added  `this.` for clarity):

```
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(before);
    return (V v) -> this.apply(before.apply(v));
}

default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> after.apply(this.apply(t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

below example shows that `andThen()` & `compose()` are contradictory methods. its produces opposite result to each other.(see output for more clarification)

`f1.andThen(f2).apply(10);` => first execute `f1.apply(10)` method. based on output first method, `f2.apply(result_of_f1_method)` method execute.

`f1.compose(f2).apply(10);` => here just opposite to `andThen()` method.
first `f2.apply()` and then `f1.apply(output_of_f2_method)` execute.

```
public class FunctionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = num -> (num - 4);
        Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = num -> (num * 2);

        // Using andThen() method
        int a=f1.andThen(f2).apply(10);
        System.out.println(a);// Output - 12

        //Using compose function
        int b=f1.compose(f2).apply(10);
        System.out.println(b);// Output - 16
    }
}
```